# How to create calender event using java date and time?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I want to create time events in Java.

For example: between March 1<sup>st</sup> to March 31<sup>st</sup> I want to create some events with start and end dates like:

- Event1: March 3 to March 5
- Event2: March 6 to March 10
- Event2: March 13 to March 25

and so on.

These events should not overlap and an event should not contain March 1<sup>st</sup> and March 31<sup>st</sup>.

How I can do it using Java date and Time or Joda-Time?
I have an only basic idea that create a class with four variables as follows:

```
monthStart
monthEnd
eventStart
eventEnd
```

Comment: Start coding. See if your idea is fine. Ask us when you have tried something and you face a problem you can solve. Not sure why you would need monthStart and monthEnd. An event goes from March 3 to March 5 (for example), so all you need is a start date and an end date. The start of the month is obviously March 1, since the event starts in March. The end of the month is obviously March 31, since the event ends in March.

Comment: For each event, check that start is after March 1, end is before March 31 and that for each other event it is either strictly before or strictly after. Use `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think a design could contain two classes: a Month class with one field, a `YearMonth`, and a collection of events; and methods for getting first and last day of the month. And an Event class, of course, with fields start and end. But the details would depend on the requirements. However Stack Overflow is not a design service, and your question is really much too broad for this format.

Comment: Your Question is not clear, as you give no algorithm for selecting particular start-stop dates in your intervals. You are also vague about specifying which month – perhaps the current date’s month? *Step 1:* Think through your problem in detail, with excruciatingly detailed step-by-step directions to solve calendar needs. *Step 2:* Assume your question has already been asked and answered – because virtually every basic date-time question has. Search thoroughly before posting. *Step 3:* `java.time.LocalDate`, `ZoneId`, `YearMonth`, optional: *ThreeTen-Extra* library’s `LocalDateRange`.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use the [Time4J API](http://time4j.net/), and create a [`DateInterval`](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/DateInterval.html) using [`PlainDate`](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainDate.html) as start and end dates:

```
// March 1st and 31st
PlainDate start = PlainDate.of(2018, 3, 1);
PlainDate end = PlainDate.of(2018, 3, 31);
DateInterval interval = DateInterval.between(start, end);
```

With this, you can check if an event is inside this interval:

```
// Event1: March 3 to March 5
PlainDate eventStart = PlainDate.of(2018, 3, 3);
PlainDate eventEnd = PlainDate.of(2018, 3, 5);
DateInterval event1 = DateInterval.between(eventStart, eventEnd);

if (interval.encloses(event1)) {
    // event1 is inside interval
}
```

You can also check if 2 events overlap:

```
// Event2: March 3 to March 5
eventStart = PlainDate.of(2018, 3, 6);
eventEnd = PlainDate.of(2018, 3, 10);
DateInterval event2 = DateInterval.between(eventStart, eventEnd);

if (event1.overlaps(event2)) {
    // events 1 and 2 overlap
}
```

Your algorithm would be: create the full interval (such as from March 1<sup>st</sup> to March 31<sup>st</sup>) and create your events intervals, and then use the methods above (`encloses` and `overlaps`) accordingly.

### Plain Java

With just Java's API, assuming you have Java 8, it's similar. The only difference is that Java doesn't have an `Interval` class and you have to compare the dates manually:

```
// March 1st and 31st
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 31);

// Event1: March 3 to March 5
LocalDate eventStart = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 3);
LocalDate eventEnd = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 5);

// check if event1 is inside start and end dates
if (start.isBefore(eventStart) && eventEnd.isBefore(end)) {
    // event is inside March 1st and 31st
}
```

`LocalDate` has the methods `isBefore` and `isAfter` to check if another date is before or after the date, and it also has the `equals` method to know if 2 dates are the same. The logic to know if 2 events overlap can be achieved by only using those methods as well, and *"it's left as an exercise to the reader"* :-)

If you have Java 7 or below, you can use the [threeten backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp), which has the `LocalDate` class as well.

#### Threeten Extra

In [this API](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/), there's an [`Interval` class](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), but it works only with `Instant`, not with `LocalDate`.

You can make some workaround on this and assume that your dates are in UTC, and then use the `Interval`. I created an auxiliary method to do such conversion:

```
public Instant toInstant(LocalDate date) {
    // convert to midnight in UTC
    return date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
}
```

And then use this to create the intervals:

```
// March 1st and 31st
Instant start = toInstant(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 1));
Instant end = toInstant(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 31));
Interval interval = Interval.of(start, end);

// Event1: March 3 to March 5
Instant eventStart = toInstant(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 3));
Instant eventEnd = toInstant(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 5));
Interval event1 = Interval.of(eventStart, eventEnd);

if (interval.encloses(event1)) {
    // event1 is inside interval
}

// Event2: March 3 to March 5
eventStart = toInstant(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 6));
eventEnd = toInstant(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 10));
Interval event2 = Interval.of(eventStart, eventEnd);

if (event1.overlaps(event2)) {
    // events 1 and 2 overlap
}
```

This is a workaround because it artificially sets the dates to midnight in UTC. As we only care about the day, month and year, though, this should do the trick (or you can also download the threeten extra's code and create another `Interval` class that works with `LocalDate`, and base your code on the original).

### Joda-Time

Joda-Time is a discontinued project and the team is advising the migration to `java.time` API. Check in [Joda-Time's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), there's a warning there saying:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)

If you use Java 6 or 7, I recommend the threeten backport. For Java >= 8, use `java.time` with threeten extra or time4j. Only if you still use Java 5, then the best alternative is to use Joda-Time (actually, the ideal is to upgrade to a newer Java version, but anyway).

In Joda-Time, [there are similar classes](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/package-summary.html): `LocalDate` and `Interval`, and you need to convert the `LocalDate` to `DateTime` (assuming midnight in UTC) in order to work with intervals (similar to the conversion to `Instant` that we made above):

```
DateTime start = new LocalDate(2018, 3, 1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime end = new LocalDate(2018, 3, 31).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);

DateTime eventStart = new LocalDate(2018, 3, 3).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime eventEnd = new LocalDate(2018, 3, 5).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);
Interval event1 = new Interval(eventStart, eventEnd);

// contains accepts the same start or end dates, it needs additional checks to make sure dates are different
if (interval.contains(event1)
    && event1.getStart().isAfter(interval.getStart())
    && event1.getEnd().isBefore(interval.getEnd())) {
    // interval contains event1, and start and end dates are not the same
}

eventStart = new LocalDate(2018, 3, 6).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);
eventEnd = new LocalDate(2018, 3, 10).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);
Interval event2 = new Interval(eventStart, eventEnd);

if (event1.overlaps(event2)) {
    // events 1 and 2 overlap
}
```

Comment: **CORRECTION:** Joda-Time is *not* discontinued. It is in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), actively maintained with critical bug fixes and with updates for `tzdata` time zone data.

Comment: About Time4J-code example: Maybe it is safer for the OP to use `contains(interval)` and `intersects(interval)` instead of `encloses()` and `overlaps()` because latter two are Allen-interval relations with a very specific meaning, see the [javadoc](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IsoInterval.html#encloses-I-) which also has diagrams illustrating the exact meaning. Another gimmick: It is possible to model full month intervals by choosing for example `CalendarMonth.of(2018, 3)`. That type can be used as parameter in the methods `contains()` and `intersects()`.